# how to omit one column while retrieving a table header in to a csv file format

Tags: oracle

I have a function in my database which retrieves all the columns of a table into a csv file. Now I want to omit only one column and show all the other columns in the result and I do not want to change the function.

How I am retrieving all the columns in to csv file is as following:

```
CPVCREATECSV := "Function_Name"('table_name') || UTL_TCP.crlf;
```

after this line, I want to omit only one column and get the rest columns. How to do that? Please help. I am doing it in Oracle.

Comment: I think you are going to have to change the underlying `SELECT`.  Or, just live with a small amount of extra data in your CSV file.

Comment: You have three options: 1. Change the function to include a list of the columns you wish to select, 2. Write some code (in Oracle or - better - outside of Oracle) to parse the file to remove the column you don't care about or 3. Have a manual step that involves opening the file in Excel, and the removing the column you don't want.